# I tried attempting a question in hacker earth and it passed for most of the tested inputs. The answer was partially accepted

Tags: c

This is the question:

[image: This is the question]

Here is the expected answer:

[image: Here is the expected answer]

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long trial, n, p, A, B, tp[10000] = {}, min;
    scanf("%li", &trial);
    for (int i = 0; i < trial; i++) {
        scanf("%li %li %li", &p, &A, &B);
        for (int m = 0, n = p; m <= p, n >= 0; m++, n--) {
            tp[m] = ((A * m * m) + (B * n * n));
        }
        min = tp[0];
        for (int j = 1; j <= p; j++) {
            if (tp[j] < min) {
                min = tp[j];
            }
        }
        printf("%li\n", min);
    }
}
```

What can I do to get the right answer?

Comment: Post the problem statement as text, not as an image. Post the exact message you get from HackerEarth about why the program does not pass. Try to identify a test case that fails.  ` = {}` is not proper C syntax and is unnecessary. When `n` is 100,000, the program overruns the `tp` array and likely takes too long. Use calculus to find a faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code:

- the initializer `= {}` will be part of the upcoming C2x standard but it is invalid in many C implementations. The array does not need initializing anyway.
- the test `m <= p, n >= 0` is somewhat incorrect: only the second part `n >= 0` is tested, the comma operator ignores the result of its left operand. This happens to suffice, but you should just write:

  ```
   for (int m = 0, n = p; m <= p; m++, n--)
  ```
- the array `tp` only has 10000 elements, which is not enough for up to 100000 (10<sup>5</sup>) cases as stated in the problem description. You probably have a buffer overflow for some test cases. Note that you can simplify the code and remove the array: you just need a single loop and keep track of the best price:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long trials = 0;
    scanf("%li", &trials);
    while (trials --> 0) {
        long p = 0, A = 0, B = 0;
        scanf("%li %li %li", &p, &A, &B);
        long min = B * p * p;
        for (long m = 1; m <= p; m++) {
            long price = A * m * m + B * (p - m) * (p - m);
            if (min > price)
                min = price;
        }
        printf("%li\n", min);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem can be solved directly using calculus, reducing the time complexity from **O(p)** to **O(1)**, which might be required to fit within the time limit of `1`, albeit 100000 iterations should be easily achieved in 1 second.

The problems consists in finding the minimum of the quadratic function *f(x) = A.x<sup>2</sup> + B.(p-x)<sup>2</sup>*

Normalizing: *f(x) = (A+B).x<sup>2</sup> - 2.B.p.x + B.p<sup>2</sup>*

First derivative: *f'(x) = 2(A+B).x - 2.B.p*

Assuming *A* and *B* are positive, the minimum is obtained for *x = B.p / (A+B)*

The solution is obtained by testing at most 2 numbers: `B * p / (A + B)` and `B * p / (A + B) + 1`

Here is an analytical solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long trials = 0;
    scanf("%li", &trials);
    while (trials --> 0) {
        long p = 0, A = 0, B = 0;
        scanf("%li %li %li", &p, &A, &B);
        // assuming A, B and p are positive
        long min = 0;
        if (A + B != 0) {
            long m = B * p / (A + B);
            if (m < 0) {  // cannot happen if A, B and p are positive
                min = B * p * p;
            } else
            if (m >= p) {
                min = A * p * p;
            } else {
                long price1 = A * m * m + B * (p - m) * (p - m);
                long price2 = A * (m + 1) * (m + 1) +
                              B * (p - m - 1) * (p - m - 1);
                min = price1 < price2 ? price1 : price2;
            }
        }
        printf("%li\n", min);
    }
    return 0;
}
```